# change text inside GWT HTMLpanel with nested widgets/html

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am using a UiBinder with GWT.  I have an HTML panel with a bunch of widgets and HTML elements in it.  I need to change the text inside the parent HTMLpanel to reflect the gender of the user (he to she type of thing).  All the text I need to change is inside different div elements (not inside any widgets) but not the same div.  Here is an example

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="parentWidget">
 <div>I think he is currently in a meeting.</div>
 <my:widget>stuff</my:widget>
 <div>I will have him call you when he gets out</div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

I was making every div with a pronoun that needed changing in to a GWT widget and then changing them one by one in the code, but now the text has grown and I want an easier way to do it.

I tried a

```
parentWidget.getElement.setInnerHTML(parentWidget.getElement.getInnerHTML().replaceAll(...)
```

but it didn't work they way I thought it would.

Any suggestions

Comment: For these kind of messages(plurals or gender depdendent) you could use the  @AlternateMessage adnotation from the Messages interface from GWT. Usually when you need to access the text or html content you should declare the @ UiField DivElement in the code. Just a suggestion

Comment: replaceAll() works with a regex. What do you mean by "it didn't work"? I agree that for a lot of text and many variations the Messages interface is the way to go, but for a simple he/she situation a regex is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others, GWT's Messages interface is the ideal way to go ahead. But still if you want to use string replacement techniques, you can do the following:

```java
NodeList<Node> childNodes = parentWidget.getElement().getChildNodes();
for(int i=0;i<childNodes.getLength(); i++){
    Node node = childNodes.getItem(i);
    if(Node.ELEMENT_NODE==node.getNodeType()){
        Element nodeEle = (Element)node;
        //use replaceAll or replace according to the requirement
        nodeEle.setInnerText(nodeEle.getInnerText().replaceAll("\\bhe\\b","she"));
    }
}
```

This way you will prevent overwriting the elements presents inside your parent widget by modifying only the text (i.e. using `replaceAll`/`replace` only on the text).